# How does maven concat multiple files that in dependencies jar with specific order?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

Project A dependency on B.jar and C.jar. They both have a sql file in resources directory:

```
A/main/src/resources/path-a-to-sql/schema.sql
B.jar/path-b-to-sql/schema.sql
C.jar/path-c-to-sql/schema.sql
```

In the project A's `pom.xml`, I want to config something to merge all `schema.sql` files from A, B, C to a single file with custom order, and output to the directory `A/target/schema.sql`. Any idea?

Comment: An SQL file does not belong into a JAR file. So there is no kind of *merge*. Apart from that thee is no order in any kind. So you have to name the SQL files accordingly...

Comment: I add `schema.sql` in `{project-dir}/main/src/resources/{path-to-sql}/schema.sql`, 
 so maven would package it into the jar file. In the jar file, it is in `{package.jar}/{path-to-sql}/schema.sql`.

Comment: Of course. I know how that works. The question is: Why is a SQL file in a JAR file? There is no option/tool which will execute the SQL within a JAR file? Only an other application (like EAR, WAR or command line tool) which uses this jar file as a dependency could do something like that...but then the SQL file belongs to that tool and not to the JAR file..?

Comment: spring-boot can execute the sql within a jar file. I make my package includes sql in the jar file because each module has its own schema.sql. And use it in the starter project.

Comment: If you are talking about a Spring Boot App we are in a different world. First in Spring boot app you have a single point where all the SQL files should belong (where the main is) located usually for things like flyway/liquibase or even without etc. and should be versionized to be able to upgrade/downgrade the DB and not being distributed over different jar files cause you have a single service which has the DB part in it..there is usually nothing distributed into module having it's own schema (which sounds like a design flaw)..How should liquibase/flyway handle that? Or any other mechanism?

Comment: Please focus on how, not why. I just want to combine all sub module's `schema.sql` to a single file.

Comment: If you see it that way my first comment already answered it to summarize it: There is no way to do this...That means you should change your projects or write your own plugin to handle this. Apart from that the `why` is important to find out what you are trying to achieve which brought me already to the conclusion that you are going the wrong way. But it's up to you to decide...You could try to use maven-shade-plugin (implement a resource transformer) or enhance the spring-boot-maven-plugin ?...everything sounds wrong to me....